# Ruby: Reading Lines from File Splitting them into Struct

Tags: ruby, struct, readlines

I have a text file that I want to read which is line separated in this format
"Item1", 1
"Item2", 34
"Item3", 6
etc.

I want to input each part of the line into a new instance of my Struct.  What syntax should I use to accomplish this?  I'm hitting a mental wall.

```
Item = Struct.new(:name, :price)
File.readlines('MASTER_INVENTORY.txt').map do |line|
  Item.new << line.split
end
```

Comment: Try `File.readlines('MASTER_INVENTORY.txt'). map { |line| Item.new(*line.split) }`.

Comment: Not quite.  My line.split is not quite right.  Each line has two items Name and Price which need to be added to each side of the Struct.  IF i hardcoded it, it would look like Item.new("teddy bear", 5)

Comment: the deliminator between records is a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item = Struct.new(:name, :price)
File.readlines('MASTER_INVENTORY.txt').map do |line|
  line.scan(/"(.*?)",\s*(\S*)/).map do |item, price|
    Item.new(item, price.to_i)
  end
end
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!  Thank you!  Thank you!   .Scan is what I needed!